# What is the most efficient way to reload a div without refreshing the whole page in django?

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I am looking for the most efficient way that I can present on a live web page data such as a table with data from the database, that when a new record is added to the database the table updates itself without the user having to refresh the page.

I have tried the method with Django and Ajax but I don't find it efficient because it has to refresh at a certain time but I only want it to refresh when a new record is added to the database.

What methods could you recommend?

Comment: ajax let you do that, maybe you are implementing in the wrong way

Comment: use a WebSocket or server-sent events to inform the client when a record is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With standard Ajax, the client has to initiate the request. If you want the server to be able to "push" to the client without a request from the client, you'll want to use websockets. There's a package called [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for implementing websockets in Django.